# Can any one send me download link for Coldfusion 11 for linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, download, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I couldn't get any active link to download Coldfusion 11 setup for Linux, can any one please help me regarding this download link.

Thanks

Comment: You should be able to find almost all prior installers for CF and related products at Gavin Pickin's CFML Repo (cfmlrepo.com). But as @BernhardDöbler said, CF11 is EOL. I wouldn't recommend installing it, unless you have a specific need to test an old CF11 site that you are upgrading to CF2016+. I definitely wouldn't put it in Production. And if the cost of a CF2018 license is out, look at Lucee. Depending on what your site uses, the effort to port a CF11 site to Lucee would probably be somewhere between not much and none. But CommandBox could also fit that role very well, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atleast! I have found this link

https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?id=0B9u7ipD8e7-oaW5fNlVvb1ZhQTQ#list

Thanks

Comment: This version is no longer publically distributed. Actually, ColdFusion 11 EOL is reached these days. In case you buy ColdFusion licences you best turn to Adobe to get older versions. Then, there's always the third party tool Commandbox. Depending on your needs.

Comment: Even if it were active, I would not trust a Google Drive link. Adobe distributes their own software.

Comment: In a comment to a thread on adobe dot com regarding an older version, Charlie Arehart recently replied: `one can find it on the community-supported CFML engine repo, called cfmlrepo.com. Or you can use this link, shared by Adobe` which even links to google drive. https://coldfusion.adobe.com/2019/03/server-2016-cf-2016/

Comment: @JamesAMohler That is a very valid point. "Hey, I've got this link to a Google Drive executable file." isn't usually a good idea to click on. At least track it back to the source and verify it's reputable.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

As has been mentioned, http://www.cfmlrepo.com/ is the community supported repository of historic CFML engines (Adobe, Lucee & Railo) and tools.

I would have posted here earlier but the site was down. It's now up.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone still looking for this - the 2021 link for CF server (UBUNTU) download is

https://documentcloud.adobe.com/link/track?uri=urn:aaid:scds:US:df35d898-6de0-4afe-bccb-03c6afbd0659

Then install as per

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/user-guide.html/coldfusion/using/install-coldfusion-2021.ug.html?fbclid=IwAR3nTq8-jaKIidXJDhX3W3BoI-UUIRirH0O8buW8qn8b2_5yyNSBT0ttpfg